# Failed building wheel for mysqlclient

Tags: python, pip, python-wheel

I downloaded wheel to the most recent version

But I'm not entirely sure how to make of this semi-cryptic error message

```
  Failed building wheel for mysql-python

  Command "/Users/username/Desktop/Project/venv/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, 
  tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/bg/_nsyc_vxasdfx___h11f3jw00000gn/T/pip-build-rBf9R1/mysql-python/setup.py';
 f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');
  f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" 
install --record /var/folders/bg/_nsyc_vx4g___xbsh11f3jw00000gn/T/pip-Tjwbij-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed 
--compile --install-headers /Users/username/Desktop/project/venv/include/site/python2.7/mysql-python" failed with error code 1 in 
/private/var/folders/bg/_nsyc_vxasdf__xbsh11f3jw00000gn/T/pip-build-rBf9R1/mysql-python/
```

I tried

```
 pip install --upgrade wheel
```

and I get

```
Requirement already up-to-date: wheel
```

MySQL version

```
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.10, for osx10.11 (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
```

Comment: I often have trouble upgrading from a whl file.  Try uninstall and the install again?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43426780/failed-building-wheel-for-mysql-python Maybe this will help you.

Comment: Couple of things: (1) have you tried any version below 14.14, and did it work? (2) what C++ compiler do you have?

Answer (score 2):

As for me, it is because my system lack of python3 developing lib. It warns that there is no "Python.h" while installing. The following command fix it for me.

`yum install python34-devel -y`

`pip3 install mysqlclient`

Answer (score 1):

The topic is quite old but for the people who might be suffered from having this problem,this can be your solution:

First of all,you must open the file where you use Python like 3.5,3.6,Anaconda etc. Then open cmd in that file and run the command below:

```
$ pip install mysqlclient==1.3.12
```