# Failed building wheel for mysql-python

Tags: mysql, mysql-python

I want to run a Django application in PyCharm which works on MySQL DB.

I am unable to connect my program to the database.

When I am trying to install MySQLclient or MySQL-python I am getting the error:

> Failed building wheel for MySQLclient

Please help me out in connecting my Django program with MySQL database.

Answer (score 9):

### Edit

Please try installing the .whl file from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/. This works every time. Just type `pip install MySQL_python‑1.2.5‑cp27‑none‑win32.whl` in the terminal.

### Original Answer

I had the same issue. You might find these steps helpful.

1. Make sure you are in an activated virtualenv when you are installing anything through pip.
2. Before you install anything, type `pip list` in the terminal to see what you have installed in the virtualenv. It should have wheel, setuptools and pip.
3. This is the part that helped me, type `pip install mysqlclient==1.3.9` or whatever version you want to install. This needs to happen before you install django.
4. Hopefully, it works and you can go ahead and install Django.

If these steps didn't work out for you, try installing MySQL-Python through the executable file here https://pypi.python.org/pypi/MySQL-python/1.2.5.

But this will only install mysql-python for you in the system. You can try `pip list` outside virtualenv to see if mysql-python is installed. If it is installed, then you have update this post so we can figure out a solution.

In the meantime some other fixes are:

- [Can't install mysql-python (newer versions) in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37092125/cant-install-mysql-python-version-1-2-5-in-windows)
- Install Visual C++ for Python and add the bin folder to the PATH environment variable.
- Make sure the mysql service is running in the background or is installed in your system by running mysql commands through the terminal.
- Sometimes, two different instances of mysql service might cause this error i.e. if you have installed mysql server or any other product multiple times in the past, you might have to get rid of the ports the past services used. In this case, do a fresh installation of mysql server and add the ~\bin path to the PATH environment variable.

Comment: When running `pip install MySQL_python‑1.2.5‑cp27‑none‑win32.whl` I get `MySQL_python‑1.2.5‑cp27‑none‑win32.whl is not a valid wheel filename.`

Comment: @jmona789 hi, i know its too old to ask but i have the same issue can you tell how does it get solved?

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem. I then uninstalled my python. Downloaded the python 3.6.5.
then used a command from

[Python 3.7, Failed building wheel for MySql-Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51117503/5719810)

the command is `pip install mysqlclient==1.3.12`

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Version 1.3.12 works. But why is having python uninstalled relevant?

Comment: After a lot of digging, it appeared to me that, 
python 3.6.5 and mysql 1.3.12 matches.
Unfortunately, using other python version such as 3.6,3.7,
I was having a hard time finding appropriate mysql version.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using `sqlalchemy`(which implicitly uses `mysql-python`) to connect to a MySQL database, updating it using `pip install sqlalchemy --upgrade` might do the trick and while creating a connection using an engine the syntax should be:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine


HOST = "your_host_name.host.com"
USER = "your_username"
PASSCODE = "your_passcode"
DATABASE = "name_of_database"

engine = create_engine(f'mysql+mysqldb://{USER}:{PASSCODE}@{HOST}/{DATABASE}')
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to install mysqlclient on Windows 10 64 bit, Django version 3.10.0

1. Download preferred mysqlclient wheel for your OS/bit size. here :
   https://pypi.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/simple/mysqlclient/
2. Point to the directory such as `C:\Users\hp\Desktop\storefront\store` from your prompt or terminal
3. install using pip i.e: `C:\Users\hp\Desktop\storefront\store > pip install mysqlclient-2.1.0-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl`

[image: print screen]

Answer (score -1):

I hope this helps.

I'm running *Python3.7* on *Windows 7* (32-bit). I had the same issue and tried using `pip` commands from windows CLI. Although, my `pip` installation was successful but I was not able to add *MySQL* or *MySQL-Connector-Python* from *Pycharm* GUI.

I used *Pycharm* Terminal for Below packages and was able to connect to *MySQL* database.

Example:

```
(PTPT) C:\Windows\System32>pip3 install mysql-connector-python==8.0.29
Collecting mysql-connector-python==8.0.29
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/32/cd/1581bfe8f5ad7fd2aecdc499f0387227ad7912419384f9393b6205a764da/mysql_connector_python-8.0.29-py2.py3-none-any.whl (342kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 348kB 409kB/s
Requirement already satisfied: protobuf>=3.0.0 in c:\users\maghy\ptpt\lib\site-packages (from mysql-connector-python==8.0.29) (3.20.1)
Installing collected packages: mysql-connector-python
  Found existing installation: mysql-connector-python 8.0.30
    Uninstalling mysql-connector-python-8.0.30:
      Successfully uninstalled mysql-connector-python-8.0.30
Successfully installed mysql-connector-python-8.0.29
WARNING: You are using pip version 19.3.1; however, version 22.2.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

pip install C:\Users\USER_NAME\Downloads\mysqlclient-1.4.6-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl
```

[PYCHARM MYSQL PACKAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zaGqU.png)