# ERROR: Failed building wheel for MySQL-python

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, mysql-python

To meet requirements of a legacy Django app, I need to install `MySQL-python==1.2.5` on a fresh virtualenv on Debian 9. However when I run

`pip install MySQL-python==1.2.5`

I get this error:

```
$ pip install MySQL-python==1.2.5
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
Collecting MySQL-python==1.2.5
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a5/e9/51b544da85a36a68debe7a7091f068d802fc515a3a202652828c73453cad/MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip
Building wheels for collected packages: MySQL-python
  Building wheel for MySQL-python (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /home/bob/.dj/bin/python2 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, ...
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for MySQL-python
 ...
    In file included from _mysql.c:44:
    /usr/include/mariadb/my_config.h:3:2: warning: #warning This file should not be included by clients, include only <mysql.h> [-Wcpp]
     #warning This file should not be included by clients, include only <mysql.h>
      ^~~~~~~
    In file included from _mysql.c:46:
    /usr/include/mariadb/mysql.h:440:3: warning: function declaration isn’t a prototype [-Wstrict-prototypes]
       MYSQL_CLIENT_PLUGIN_HEADER
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    _mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject_ping’:
    _mysql.c:2005:41: error: ‘MYSQL’ {aka ‘struct st_mysql’} has no member named ‘reconnect’
      if ( reconnect != -1 ) self->connection.reconnect = reconnect;
                                             ^
    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /home/bob/.dj/bin/python2 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-29DwM6/MySQL-python/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-29DwM6/MySQL-python/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-nI8a9C/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/bob/.dj/include/site/python2.7/MySQL-python Check the logs for full command output.
```

There is [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43426780/failed-building-wheel-for-mysql-python), but the suggestions there did not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue. I guess the `mysql-python` relies some files from mysql driver (or library?).

1. Make sure you don't run in **Debian** like me. The official python image such as [python:2.7](https://hub.docker.com/layers/python/library/python/2.7/images/sha256-bf3ab881bf19bb40497cf97172c95f98af50a556d4005d15c3f2ef983b38cae6?context=explore)
   was built on Debian. It turns out that Debian 10 was shipped with MariaDB and there are some differences between its API and Mysql's API
2. For others, you can try the following commands to see if it works

   ```sh
   # on Mac
   brew install mysql-connector-c 
   brew install mysql@5.7

   # on Ubuntu
   apt-get install -y default-libmysqlclient-dev
   ```