# ERROR: Failed building wheel for mysqlclient

Tags: mysql, django, python-3.6, psycopg2

I'm unable to 'pip install mysqlclient', and every attempt returns the error: 'ERROR: Failed building wheel for mysqlclient'. For context, I'm running on macOS Mojave 10.14.5. The rest of this post assumes that both 'python==3.6' and 'virtualenv' are already downloaded. In addition, x-code command line tools are already installed (not that I think that matters).

The steps to this are (from command line):

1. 'virtualenv ~/venv'

   - Output:

   Using base prefix '/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6'
   New python executable in /Users/usr1/venv/bin/python3.6
   Also creating executable in /Users/usr1/venv/bin/python
   Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done."
2. 'source ~/venv/bin/activate'
3. 'pip install mysqlclient'

So far, I've viewed and attempted everything on:

1. [Failed building wheel for mysqlclient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40413712/failed-building-wheel-for-mysqlclient)
2. ["Failed building wheel for psycopg2" - MacOSX using virtualenv and pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34304833/failed-building-wheel-for-psycopg2-macosx-using-virtualenv-and-pip)
3. [Failed building wheel for mysql-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43426780/failed-building-wheel-for-mysql-python)

   Collecting mysqlclient
     Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f4/f1/3bb6f64ca7a429729413e6556b7ba5976df06019a5245a43d36032f1061e/mysqlclient-1.4.2.post1.tar.gz
   Building wheels for collected packages: mysqlclient
     Building wheel for mysqlclient (setup.py) ... error
     ERROR: Complete output from command /Users/usr1/venv/bin/python3.6 -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='"'"'/private/var/folders/2j/1qt0_7q96lxbxl2w5kx8r1zr0000gn/T/pip-install-4uobjq_4/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /private/var/folders/2j/1qt0_7q96lxbxl2w5kx8r1zr0000gn/T/pip-wheel-ehvuw9uv --python-tag cp36:
     ERROR: running bdist_wheel
     running build
     running build_py
     creating build
     creating build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6
     creating build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
     copying MySQLdb/**init**.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
     copying MySQLdb/_exceptions.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
     copying MySQLdb/compat.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
     copying MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
     copying MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
     copying MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
     copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
     copying MySQLdb/times.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
     creating build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
     copying MySQLdb/constants/**init**.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
     copying MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
     copying MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
     copying MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
     copying MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
     copying MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
     running build_ext
     building 'MySQLdb._mysql' extension
     creating build/temp.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6
     creating build/temp.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
     clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Dversion_info=(1,4,2,'post',1) -D__version__=1.4.2.post1 -I/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.19/include/mysql -I/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/include/python3.6m -c MySQLdb/_mysql.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/_mysql.o
     clang -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup build/temp.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/_mysql.o -L/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.19/lib -lmysqlclient -lssl -lcrypto -o build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/_mysql.cpython-36m-darwin.so
     ld: library not found for -lssl
     clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
     error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1

   ---

   ERROR: Failed building wheel for mysqlclient
     Running setup.py clean for mysqlclient
   Failed to build mysqlclient
   Installing collected packages: mysqlclient
     Running setup.py install for mysqlclient ... error
       ERROR: Complete output from command /Users/usr1/venv/bin/python3.6 -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='"'"'/private/var/folders/2j/1qt0_7q96lxbxl2w5kx8r1zr0000gn/T/pip-install-4uobjq_4/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/2j/1qt0_7q96lxbxl2w5kx8r1zr0000gn/T/pip-record-zvd4oedq/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/usr1/venv/bin/../include/site/python3.6/mysqlclient:
       ERROR: running install
       running build
       running build_py
       creating build
       creating build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6
       creating build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
       copying MySQLdb/**init**.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
       copying MySQLdb/_exceptions.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
       copying MySQLdb/compat.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
       copying MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
       copying MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
       copying MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
       copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
       copying MySQLdb/times.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
       creating build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
       copying MySQLdb/constants/**init**.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
       copying MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
       copying MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
       copying MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
       copying MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
       copying MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
       running build_ext
       building 'MySQLdb._mysql' extension
       creating build/temp.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6
       creating build/temp.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
       clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Dversion_info=(1,4,2,'post',1) -D__version__=1.4.2.post1 -I/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.19/include/mysql -I/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/include/python3.6m -c MySQLdb/_mysql.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/_mysql.o
       clang -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup build/temp.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/_mysql.o -L/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.19/lib -lmysqlclient -lssl -lcrypto -o build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/_mysql.cpython-36m-darwin.so
       ld: library not found for -lssl
       clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
       error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1
       ----------------------------------------
   ERROR: Command "/Users/usr1/venv/bin/python3.6 -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='"'"'/private/var/folders/2j/1qt0_7q96lxbxl2w5kx8r1zr0000gn/T/pip-install-4uobjq_4/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/2j/1qt0_7q96lxbxl2w5kx8r1zr0000gn/T/pip-record-zvd4oedq/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/usr1/venv/bin/../include/site/python3.6/mysqlclient" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/2j/1qt0_7q96lxbxl2w5kx8r1zr0000gn/T/pip-install-4uobjq_4/mysqlclient/

CONCLUSION: Ideally, I would like for 'pip' to simply install 'mysqlclient'. I would very much appreciate the help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Only need to install dev version of python with:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-dev
```

[ERROR: Failed building wheel for mysqlclient](https://serverok.in/error-failed-building-wheel-for-mysqlclient)

Comment: I faced same issue on python3, flask and sqlalchemy with virtual environment. I installed python3-dev with `sudo apt-get install python3-dev` command that resolved my issues.

Answer (score 1):

When you are installing the mysqlclient Python library on your computer, you may encounter an error saying **Failed building wheel for mysqlclient** .

If you are using **Debian/ Ubuntu** then run the following commands:

> sudo apt-get install python3-dev default-libmysqlclient-dev build-essential

If you are using **Red Hat/ CentOS** then run the following commands:

> sudo yum install python3-devel mysql-devel

If the above commands running is finished then try to run this command again on your computer.

> pip install mysqlclient

I hope everything works fine as you have expected.
**Happy Coding :)**

Answer (score 0):

Download mysqlclient.whl from this
[Python Extension Package for Windows](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysqlclient) and install with `pip install mysqlclient‑1.4.2‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl`

Comment: Rin Nguyen, I appreciate the advice but would the windows binaries still apply given that I'm running a unix system (macOS)?