# unable to install mysqlclient for django in virtual environment

Tags: mysql, django, python-3.x

I am new to django

I have created virtual enviroment of python3.6

while installing mysqlclient in virtual environment, it is showing bellow error

```
(myVirtualEnv) [root@avinash helloWorld]# pip install mysqlclient
Collecting mysqlclient
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d0/97/7326248ac8d5049968bf4ec708a5d3d4806e412a42e74160d7f266a3e03a/mysqlclient-1.4.6.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: mysqlclient
  Building wheel for mysqlclient (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /home/avinash/pythonProjects/myVirtualEnv/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-o154owc4/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-o154owc4/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-vbtdntog --python-tag cp36
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-o154owc4/mysqlclient/
  Complete output (30 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/_exceptions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/compat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/times.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
  running build_ext
  building 'MySQLdb._mysql' extension
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
  gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -Dversion_info=(1,4,6,'final',0) -D__version__=1.4.6 -I/usr/include/mysql -I/usr/include/mysql/mysql -I/usr/include/python3.6m -c MySQLdb/_mysql.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/_mysql.o
  gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-z,relro -g build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/_mysql.o -L/usr/lib64/ -L/usr/lib64 -lmariadb -lpython3.6m -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/_mysql.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
  /bin/ld: cannot find -lmariadb
  collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
  error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for mysqlclient
  Running setup.py clean for mysqlclient
Failed to build mysqlclient
Installing collected packages: mysqlclient
    Running setup.py install for mysqlclient ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /home/avinash/pythonProjects/myVirtualEnv/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-o154owc4/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-o154owc4/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-1pdt4sxo/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/avinash/pythonProjects/myVirtualEnv/include/site/python3.6/mysqlclient
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-o154owc4/mysqlclient/
    Complete output (30 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/_exceptions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/compat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/times.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
    running build_ext
    building 'MySQLdb._mysql' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
    gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -Dversion_info=(1,4,6,'final',0) -D__version__=1.4.6 -I/usr/include/mysql -I/usr/include/mysql/mysql -I/usr/include/python3.6m -c MySQLdb/_mysql.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/_mysql.o
    gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-z,relro -g build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/_mysql.o -L/usr/lib64/ -L/usr/lib64 -lmariadb -lpython3.6m -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/_mysql.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
    /bin/ld: cannot find -lmariadb
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /home/avinash/pythonProjects/myVirtualEnv/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-o154owc4/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-o154owc4/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-1pdt4sxo/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/avinash/pythonProjects/myVirtualEnv/include/site/python3.6/mysqlclient Check the logs for full command output.
```

I searched for it, did not get any useful information on net
checked below links

[Failed building wheel for mysqlclient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40413712/failed-building-wheel-for-mysqlclient)

["Failed building wheel for psycopg2" - MacOSX using virtualenv and pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34304833/failed-building-wheel-for-psycopg2-macosx-using-virtualenv-and-pip)

[ERROR: Failed building wheel for mysqlclient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56692800/error-failed-building-wheel-for-mysqlclient)

[Failed building wheel for mysql-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43426780/failed-building-wheel-for-mysql-python)

> It is working fine without virtual environment

thanks in advance

Comment: install python3-dev

Comment: it is already installed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My issue has been resolved after installing
MariaDB-shared package in CentOS

> yum install MariaDB-shared